# Is it true that for a Group $G$ with Normal Group $N: G/N = GN/N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Is it true that for a Group $G$ with Normal Group $N: G/N = GN/N$?

I think the statement is correct. But why do we have to write: $[G,G]N/N$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121516/quotient-group-commutator) instead of just $[G,G]/N$?

Thanks!

Comment: $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, but it's not necessarily a subgroup of $[G,G]$. It is, however, a (normal) subgroup of $[G,G]N$ — why?

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that, but then thought, that it's obviously also normal in $[G,G]$ and forgot that it also has to be a subgroup in order to be a normal subgroup.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal group"? We usually talk about 'normal subgroups", since the definition of "normal" talks about elements outside the putative normal subgroup. If $N$ is **any** subgroup of $G$, then $GN = G$, so the equation in your title is trivial. But then the second paragraph of your question talks about the commutator subgroup $[G, G]$. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

$[G,G]N/N$ is the image of $[G,G]$ under the canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G/N$. This homomorphism respects taking commutators. So in particular $[G/N,G/N]=[G,G]N/N$.

Answer (score 0):

(1) $N$ is normal **subgroup** of $G$; so it is normal *subgroup* of every subgroup between $N$ and $G$.

(2) When talking of (some subgroup)$/N$, this (some subgroup) should be taken *containing* $N$.

(3) We ask: given a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, does it always contain $[G,G]$? You can easily see negative answer by taking simple examples of finite order groups $G$.

(4) Thus, when we want to factor $[G,G]$ by $N$, first look *smallest subgroup above $N$*(=containing $N$) which contains $[G,G]$; it is precisely $[G,G]N$.

I hope this will clarify your doubt.